# Magento 2 - opcache forbidden error

Tags: magento2, nginx, error-log

I'm using Magento 2. 
Suddenly appeared below error in the Nginx error log.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

> 2020/02/25 12:51:24 [error] 10295#0: *183747840 directory index of "/var/www/html/opcache/" is forbidden, client: 172.38.10.96, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "54.168.168.25"

Comment: follow this link :- https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Magento-2-and-Nginx-error/td-p/45648

Comment: Answer is not there

Comment: why you need this folder for?

Comment: I dont need. But this shows in error log

Comment: if you dont have this folder and its not configured in `opcache.file_cache` then forget about it.